# Google Command Notebook in background

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to run a Google Colab notebook that needs to make use of a GPU environment and may take quite long to end. I am trying to do the process as encapsulated as possible so I do not loose the work doe before if Google Colab disconnects, but it is quite difficult to do so. Therefore, I'd like to know:

1. Is there any way to leave a Google Colab execution executing even if I am not directly connected to the environment (thus, leave the process in background without the need of having the notebook open).
2. If that is not an option, is there any way I can continue executing a comand keeping the last state? I mean, if there is a way in which I can tell Google Colab to contnue right where the execution stopped the last time.
3. I'd also appreciate any suggestion on how to go saving the needed information. I am trying to train an RL model with the following code:

Would there be a way to save the state of the model in a certain epoch and continue training from it the next time the process runs?

def train_agent(self, n_steps = 2048, total_timesteps = 50000, callback=None, log_interval=1, tb_log_name='AgentV1', reset_num_timesteps=True, progress_bar=False):

```
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")
    print(f"           Training agent {self.model_name}")
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")

    # wrap the environment with a Monitor wrapper to track statistics
    log_dir = "./logs/"
    os.makedirs(log_dir, exist_ok=True)
    mean_reward = ' - '

    # Monitor(self.gym_env , log_dir)

    # train the agent
    best_mean_reward, best_model_path = -float('inf'), None
    for i in range(1, int(total_timesteps/n_steps)+1):
        self.learn(total_timesteps=total_timesteps, callback=callback, log_interval=log_interval,
                     tb_log_name=tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar=progress_bar)
        # evaluate the agent and log the results
        mean_reward = self.evaluate()
        if mean_reward > best_mean_reward:
            best_mean_reward = mean_reward
            best_model_path = f"{self.model_name}_{i}"
            self.save(best_model_path)
            print(f"New best model saved to {best_model_path}")

    # plot the training results
    results_plotter.plot_results([log_dir], total_timesteps, results_plotter.X_TIMESTEPS, tb_log_name)
    fig = results_plotter.plot_results([log_dir], total_timesteps, results_plotter.X_TIMESTEPS, tb_log_name)
    plot_file = f"training_results_{utils.getDateTime()}.png"
    plt.savefig(plot_file)  # save the plot as a file
    plt.close(fig)  # close the plot to free up memory
    utils.senTrainingEndEmail(tb_log_name, mean_reward, plot_file)
```